# How to integrate Bugzilla with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bugzilla

Please explain how can i integrate **Bugzilla** with **Jenkins**.

Steps i have done till now are below:

1. Installed Bugzilla and Jenkins in local system
2. Able to access both applications
3. Installed Bugzilla plugin in Jenkins application
4. When i tried to add Bugzilla URL in Jenkins showing error, Screenshot attached.
   [Bugzilla Plugin Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbLG3.png)
5. My Expectation is to perform as given in this link
   https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bugzilla+Plugin

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your bugzilla url. You need to change https://localhost to http://localhost

I hope your issue will be solved.